# Очень мощная отладка javascript

Tags: отладка, javascript

Сейчас впервые начал разрабатывать поистине мощное веб-приложение. Сразу почувствовал необходимость наличие нормального отладчика. Хромовские (больше всего я люблю его) штучки это конечно хорошо, но сейчас мне нужно что-то больше. Ну вот мои требования:

Приложение все время говорит - какую строчку она делает, какие события срабатывают, где какая переменная скольким ровна и т.д. Короче хочу знать всё!!!

P.s. Конечно можно написать свой (или юзать чужой) фреймворк, который фиксирует в консоли (console.log() ), который обо всём говорит. Но мне нужна именно специализированная программа под win (буду рад если она основана на chromium), которая сожданна для этих целей.

Comment: FireBug не подойдет? Кстати, есть его [версия и под Chrome](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

Comment: не, нужно что-то по мощнее

Comment: @Deonis - сам по себе firebug ничем не лучше, на мой взгляд даже хуже chrome dev tools.

А Firebug под хром это как internet explorer под mac, можно конечно, но зачем?

Comment: Голова - вот самый мощный отладчик.

Comment: @avp - в голове, к сожалению, слишком мало оперативной памяти и, к тому-же, выделение и освобождение оной реализовано со страшными багами, это я еще молчу об утечках, единственное спасение от которых - сон, руки бы поотбивать тому, кто писал этот отладчик... :)

Comment: А задача-то какая? "разрабатывать поистине мощное веб-приложение" или получить незабываемые ощущения от работы с "поистине мощным веб-приложением" под крутейшим отладчиком? Если первое -- то от отладчиков надо потихоньку отходить...

Comment: @alexlz отходить от отладчиков? Почему? Чего плохого?

Comment: @danpetruk В отладчиках (хороших) ничего плохого нет. Они нужны и полезны. Но вот планирование их использования для разработки -- смущает. Лучше не создавать ситуации, где без отладчика -- труба (в том числе и не полагаться на средства языка/инструменты, которых не знаешь или почти не знаешь). Лучше писать проще и понятней, чем потом отладчиком искать ошибку в наворченном, но бестолковом коде.

Ну и не забывать правило: нашёл одну ошибку, значит должна быть и другая.

Comment: @alexlz труба только сейчас образовалась. До этого я про них и недумал

Comment: @danpetruk, попытки поднять интерес к вопросу искусственно мало когда приводят к ожидаемому результату

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А если попробовать IDE WebStorm? http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm
У них неплохой экстеншн для отладки должен быть. На [этом видео](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/demos/js_debugger.html) показан функционал дебаггера.

Answer (score 3):

[Брекпоинты](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints) дают такую возможность. Причем именно в тех местах js-кода, где это в данный момент нужно.

Comment: Брекпоинты это конечно хорошо, но после каждого брекпоинта надо выполнять дополнительные действия, чтобы узнать где что. А это не очень удобно. А хочется что-то удобное, и без геморройного.

Comment: @danpetruk - пишите Unit тесты и будет вам счастье, если вас не устраивает функционал оных, то вам нужен искусственный интеллект, который будет знать что, где, как выводить :)

Как вариант - пишите тесты, запускаете в phantom.js, в нем-же пишите обвертку для вывода результатов на консоль, либо в файл, либо в pdf, как вам удобнее, profit

Answer (score 3):

Помимо упомянутых выше [Web-/PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/index.html#JavaScript_Debugger_Based_on_Mozilla) и встроенного отладчика в [Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts), нельзя не упомянуть про [Visual Studio Professional](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/rus/products/visual-studio-professional-2012) - как ни странно, но это мощнейшая среда имеет огромные возможности для отладки javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже написали - для этого существуют breakpoint'ы. Для примера:

```
function test() {
    // функция которую нужно отладить
    var someVar = 'someValue';
    debugger;
}

test();
```

После вызова функции мы попадаем в breakpoint, когда мы в нем - открываем консоль и узнаем все что нам нужно, например: `console.log(someVar)`. Так-же мы можем просмотреть все переменные текущего Scope и изменять их значения. Естественно у любого отладчика есть возможность продолжить выполнение JS'а.